# Is manually updating a for loop iterator bad practice?

Tags: java, processing-efficiency

I have a program that loops over a list of vehicle co-ordinates and then performs other functions on them. I am only looking for pairs of successive co-ordinates that are not too close together. If a vehicle is stationary for a long time, there is the potential for thousands of successive co-ordinates to be on top of each other.

Once I find my two co-ordinates, I am manually updating my iterator (i=j-1) so that I don't have to go over the many thousands of co-ordinates repeatedly. My question is, is this good practice? Or is there a viable alternative? I could not find any examples of this online. I saw the 'continue' statement, however this seemed like it would require an extra if statement, and the manual update was more 'elegant'.

```
int LatLngSize = latLngList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < LatLngSize; i++) {
    j = i + 1;
    validPoints = true;
    if (LatLngSize > j) {
        latLng1.setCoordinate(latLngList.get(i));
        latLng2.setCoordinate(latLngList.get(j));
        consecutivePointDistance = latLng1.distance(latLng2);
    }
    while (consecutivePointDistance < 0.05) {
        j++;
        if (LatLngSize > j) {
            latLng2.setCoordinate(latLngList.get(j));
            consecutivePointDistance = latLng1.distance(latLng2);
            i = j - 1; // This is the potential offender.
        } else {
            validPoints = false;
            consecutivePointDistance = 100;
        }   
    }

    //Do stuff with my latlng1 and latlng2
}
```

Comment: It is not very pretty, but it's valid. Typically you might rewrite as a `while` loop - then the fact that you update your outer loop parameter differently depending on the conditions is more obvious. Typically a `for` loop is expected to run with the same increment each time. It makes your code a little bit harder to follow - and thus more prone to bugs.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything like this. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672975/is-manually-updating-a-for-loop-iterator-bad-practice/19673075#19673075.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is bad practice.  It will compile and run just fine, but in answer to your question, it is bad practice.

If you want to manually update your iterator, use a `while` loop.

Anything you can do with a `for` loop can also be done with a `while` loop.  The choice in what loop to actually implement is a matter of readability.  In `for` loops, people expect the iterator to be updated in the update statement and only in the update statement.

If you can't figure out how to rewrite your loop so your iterator is updated only in the update statement, consider something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<someValue; ++i /*i also updated at line 18*/)
```

Just as an example.  This is still worse than rewriting the code so it's not updated at line 18 (or whatever line) but far better than updating it at line 18 and not leaving the comment here in the update statement.

Alternatively, per comments on this answer, try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<someValue; /*see body*/) {
    //do stuff
    //update i
    //do stuff
}
```

Now in this case, your update statement is completely empty, so even without the `/*see body*/` comment, anyone maintaining your code already know that `i` must be modified somewhere within the body.  And the `++i` behavior from the update statement can be recreated simply by adding `++i` as the last line of the `for` loop.

Comment: I sometimes use the syntax: `for (int i = 0; i < LatLngSize; /*see body*/ ) { /* modify i in here */ }`

Comment: @DerFlatulator Haha, I must've been editing that in as you left the comment.  I've never done that myself personally, but just had that thought after posting my answer.  Although, your version actually has an empty update statement, which is probably the best version.

Comment: I do pay special attention to leave a brief comment to make sure that people reading it note that the iterating value is modified inside the body of the loop. Unfortunately people see a for loop and make assumptions.

Comment: @nhgrif I never really thought of using a while loop. I've always thought as a while loop as "I want to do stuff until something changes" and a for loop as "I want to go through an entire list of things".... 

I should also add that this for loop is nested within another for loop, that iterates through a list of bridges, to compare the location of the vehicle with every bridge. By using two for loops I think it is a little clearer what is going on. But it wont be difficult to rewrite for a while loop.

Comment: @MattQuinlan I typically think of the loops in that same manner, but you can rewrite any `for` loop as a `while` loop and vice versa.  In the end, it's ALL about readability.  If they're equally optimal, always do what's most readable.  And updating a `for` loop iterator outside the update statement is confusing, so if you ABSOLUTELY MUST do it, leave a comment where the update statement should be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It's a bad practice.  Don't do it.  If I'm maintaining your code, and I see

```
for (int i = 0; i < latLngSize; i++)
```

I take this to mean that `i` increases by one, over and over, from 0 until it reaches `latLngSize`.  I don't look further for other instances of `i` changing.  So, change `i` at your peril, and only if you don't mind incurring the wrath of all future developers.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
int size = latLngList.size();
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++) {
    latLng1.setCoordinate(latLngList.get(i));
    latLng2.setCoordinate(latLngList.get(i+1));
    if(latLng1.distance(latLng2) >= 0.05) {
        //Do stuff with my latlng1 and latlng2
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can simplify the supplied code. Even starting the iterator at 1 would help. It's just a work in progress at the moment still to be improved and I'm not the best at writing code just yet.

Comment: Matt, it's time you heard the saying "premature optimization is the root of all evil." You were worried about the elegance of adding one more statement when really getting working/straightforward drafts is a higher priority.